# Why doesn't redirect work when im creating an user?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Can someone please help me? my res.redirect doesn't work at the moment. It worked a couple of days ago - It can't solve this problem. TBH, I don't know why it won't work as I have used res.redirect multiple times in my code

```
server.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '../../View/createUser.html')); //__dirname returnerer stien til denne fil og path.join sammensætter de to stier
});
server.post("/createUserPost", function(req, res) {
    var brugernavn = req.body.Brugernavn;
    var password2 = req.body.password;
    var email2 = req.body.email;
    var alder = req.body.Alder;
    var fornavn1 = req.body.fornavn;
    var efternavn1 = req.body.efternavn;
    var gender = req.body.Køn;

    //Vi konstruerer det array, som skal indsættes i vores mysql-database (skal defineres med curly brackets)
    var post = {username: brugernavn, password: password2, email: email2, age: alder, firstname: fornavn1, lastname: efternavn1, gender: gender};

    if(brugernavn != "" && password2 != "" && email2 != "" && alder != "" && fornavn1 != "" && efternavn1 != "" && gender != "") {
        connection.query("INSERT INTO sys.users SET ?", post, function (error, results, fields) {
        if(error) throw error;
           res.redirect("/hovedside");
        });
    } else {
        res.send({ping:'Error: missing information'});
    }

    
});
```

Comment: try to add some console.logs to check where your code is going (if it reaches res.redirect). You can also debug your code with eg. webstorm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#node_debugging_overview

Answer (score 1):

Your code probably falls here: `if(error) throw error;` and not continue to the redirect. put logs and find out why your query failed to be executed.